# Why camera is not working on Xamarin WebView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a simple Xamarin Page that calls a WebRTC page in a WebView:
The page works fine on Chrome on the same Android device, but don't work on WebView saying no errors!.

AndroidManifest.xaml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.dpwcam">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="DPWCAM.Android" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

MyWebViewRenderer.cs :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace DPWCAM.Droid
{
    class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        Activity mContext;
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            this.mContext = context as Activity;
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.UserAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
            Control.ClearCache(true);
            Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebClient(mContext));
        }
        public class MyWebClient : WebChromeClient
        {
            Activity mContext;
            public MyWebClient(Activity context)
            {
                this.mContext = context;
            }
            [TargetApi(Value = 21)]
            public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
            {
                mContext.RunOnUiThread(() => {
                    request.Grant(request.GetResources());

                });
            }

            public override bool OnConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage)
            {
                var message = consoleMessage.Message();
                return base.OnConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyWebView.cs :

```
public class MyWebView : WebView
    {
    }
```

WebViewPage.xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="CameraName"></Entry>
            <Button x:Name="Navigate" Clicked="NavigateButton_Clicked" Text="Save"></Button>
            <dpwcam:MyWebView
                x:Name="webView"
                HeightRequest="500"
                WidthRequest="500"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

WebViewPage.xaml.cs :

```
void NavigateButton_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs args)
        {
            _cameraName = CameraName.Text;
            
            webView.Source = $"https://cam.AnyDomain.com.tr?Name={_cameraName}";
            
        }
```

I then started googling for an answer and didn’t find a solution for my case. All answers I found is about permissions which I already did

So whats wrong ? Thanks

Comment: When targetSdkVersion is greater than 23, there may be a situation where the mobile video cannot be displayed (the camera is not automatically turned on), and dynamic authorization is required.

Comment: You don't seem to be requesting runtime permissions correctly.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT thanks for answer, it was about runtime permissions, its my fault :(

Comment: @Cheesebaron thanks you are right :)